# Integrate minted syntax highlighted code into non-english text?

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting

I believe I am constructing a cannon to hit a mosquito

```
\newcommand{\src}[1]{\selectlanguage{english}{\mint{sh}/ #1 /}
\selectlanguage{greek}}
```

everything inside the brackets of a `\src{}` command would not be shown in the same line as desired but in a verbatim environment. How can I manipulate this? Is it a feature that already exists?

Comment: You might also try on http://tex.stackexchange.com  it is like stackoverflow but for tex and latex

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `minted` always uses `\Verbatim` at the moment, because Pygments always produces a `\Verbatim` output, which can’t be influenced.

A feature request for inline code has already been submitted to the Pygments developers.

But in the current version it’s not yet integrated so at the moment there’s unfortunately no solution for this problem.